# Game center achievements in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, achievements

In my app i'm able to add game center achievements successfully. But i'm not able to reset those achievements. I tried the methods described in the Apple's Game kit tutorial, but still i can't reset once added achievements in the game center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have you tried from the Apple's GameKit Tutorials?

This should work regardless of what you use (UIKit, Cocos2d):

Find your authenticate method and call the reset achievements method: i.e

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {


[GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"achievements reset");
        }];

}];
```

Don't forget to comment the reset method when you're done, or else you'll be reseting the achievements every time you log in to Game Center. Let me know how it goes.